# How to make double sort integer arrays using C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have 3-column integer arrays, whose last 2 elements are for sorting. For example

> 10 0 1
>
> 11 0 2
>
> 12 1 2
>
> 13 0 1

I want them to become:

> 10 0 1
>
> 13 0 1
>
> 11 0 2
>
> 12 1 2

The arrays are first sorted according to the 2nd column, and then again according to 3rd column.

I have over 3000 rows, so I need something also fast. How can you do this in c++?

Note: The array will be allocated dynamically using the following templates:

```
template <typename T>
T **AllocateDynamic2DArray(int nRows, int nCols){
    T **dynamicArray;

    dynamicArray = new T*[nRows];
    for( int i = 0 ; i < nRows ; i++ ){
        dynamicArray[i] = new T[nCols];
        for ( int j=0; j<nCols;j++){
            dynamicArray[i][j]= 0;
        }
    }
    return dynamicArray;
}
```

in main,

int ** lineFilter = AllocateDynamic2DArray(2*numberOfLines,3);

Comment: 3000 rows is very small; just about anything you do in the comparator that you pass to `std::sort` will do the trick.

Comment: In your example, the records `10 0 1` and `13 0 1` compare equal according to the sort criteria. You have chosen to place them in the output in a particular order, but you have not said how that order was chosen. `std::sort` will not necessarily put them in that order you chose.

Comment: @Steve Jessop the order is not important.

Comment: You have to give the type-signature of the array, and describe how you are allocating it.

Comment: Is using qsort() acceptable? C instead of C++ but it's easy with it and can be used on C++ code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
template<typename T>
struct compareRows {
    bool operator() (T * const & a, T * const & b) {
        if (a[1] == b[1])
            return a[2] < b[2];
        else
            return a[1] < b[1];
    }
};

std::sort(dynamicArray, dynamicArray+nrows, compareRows<int>());
```

Use a functor to implement the comparison between the rows. The sort will take pointers to the beginning of each row and swap them according to the contents of the rows. The rows will stay in the same places in memory.

Answer (score 4):

you can use `std::sort()`; however, this is complicated by your array being 2D.

In general, `std::sort()` can't eat 2D arrays; you have to create a class to cast around the compiler warnings and complaints:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int data[4][3] = {
    {10,0,1},
    {11,0,2},
    {12,1,2},
    {13,0,1}
};

struct row_t { // our type alias for sorting; we know this is compatible with the rows in data
    int data[3];
    bool operator<(const row_t& rhs) const {
        return (data[1]<rhs.data[1]) || ((data[1]==rhs.data[1]) && (data[2]<rhs.data[2]));
    }
};              

int main() {
    std::sort((row_t*)data,(row_t*)(data+4));
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
        std::cout << i << '=' << data[i][0] << ',' << data[i][1] << ',' << data[i][2] << ';' << std::endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

It becomes much easier if you use a `std::vector` to hold your items that really are of type `row_t` or such.  Vectors are dynamically sized and sortable.

Comment: If the data structure is `int [][3]`, then he can't.  C style arrays are broken, and don't work as element types with the STL.

Comment: @JamesKanze you are replying pre-edit where I pasted working code? Indeed, I was expecting -1 from the beginning and surprised how many people just upvote like sheep without understanding the problem ;)

Comment: yes, this code doesn't work if data is allocated dynamically.

Comment: @Will Your solution (post-edit) has undefined behavior; you're accessing an object through an lvalue which is not of its type.  In practice, it could fail if the optimization levels are turned up (at least with g++, but I expect with other compilers as well).  The only real solution is to make it an array (or a vector) of some sort of real type, and not of an array.

Comment: @JamesKanze completely agree that real types are the way to go; but in this example, the guarantees about memory layout of arrays apply so its not all undefined.

Comment: @Will You have an object with type `int[3]`.  You access it through an lvalue of type `row_t`.  That's undefined behavior.  More importantly, g++ (and probably other compilers) will assume that writes through a `row_t` cannot possibly change the value of an `int[3]`, and optimize accordingly; e.g. it remembers that `data[0][0]` was set to 10 before the sort, and so when it is accessed after the sort, the compiler will simply use the constant 10, without rereading the array.

Answer (score 1):

OK, the OP has a three-column integer arrays, which is not straightforward to sort, because you can't assign arrays.

One option is to have arrays of structs, where the struct contains one element for each column, write a custom compare routine and use `std::sort`.

Another option is to *pretend* we have such an array of structs and employ the evilness of `reinterpret_cast`, like below:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct elt_t
{
  int e0;
  int e1;
  int e2;
};

int
compare (const elt_t &a, const elt_t &b)
{
  if (a.e1 == b.e1)
    return a.e2 < b.e2;
  else
    return a.e1 < b.e1;
}

int a [10][3] = 
{
  { 10, 0, 1 },
  { 11, 0, 2 },
  { 12, 1, 2 },
  { 13, 0, 1 }
};


int
main ()
{
  std::sort (reinterpret_cast<elt_t *>(&a[0]),
             reinterpret_cast<elt_t *>(&a[4]), compare);

  int i, j;

  for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    std::cout << a [i][0] << ", " << a [i][1] << ", " << a [i][2] << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Of course, whether or not this is standards compliant is highly debatable :)

**EDIT:**

With the added requirement for the matrix to by dynamically allocated, you can use an array of `std::vector`, or a vector of `std::vector`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int
compare (const std::vector<int> &a, const std::vector<int> &b)
{
  if (a[1] == b[1])
    return a[2] < b[2];
  else
    return a[1] < b[1];
}


std::vector<int> *
make_vec (unsigned int r, unsigned int c)
{
  std::vector<int> *v = new std::vector<int> [r];

  /* Don't care for column count for the purposes of the example.  */
  v [0].push_back (10); v [0].push_back (0); v [0].push_back (1);
  v [1].push_back (11); v [1].push_back (0); v [1].push_back (2);
  v [2].push_back (12); v [2].push_back (1); v [2].push_back (2);
  v [3].push_back (13); v [3].push_back (0); v [3].push_back (1);

  return v;
}

int
main ()
{
  std::vector<int> *v = make_vec (4, 3);

  std::sort (&v[0], &v[4], compare);

  int i, j;

  for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    std::cout << v[i][0] << ", " << v [i][1] << ", " << v [i][2] << std::endl;

  delete [] v;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @EmreTurkoz, check the second version.

Answer (score 0):

use this for the second column and then for the third. Now it works  for single dim arrays

```
   int *toplace(int *start, int *end)
{
    int *i = start+1, *j= end-1;

    while(i<=j)
    {
    while(*i<=*start && i<=j) {i++;}
    while(*j>=*start && i<=j) {j--;}    
    if (i<j) std::swap(*i++,*j--); 
    }

    std::swap(*start,*(i-1)); 
    return i-1;
}



void quicksort(int *start, int *end)
{
    if (start >= end) return;

    int *temp = start;
    temp = toplace(start,end);

    quicksort(start,temp);
    quicksort(temp+1,end);

}
```

Comment: Why write your own quicksort when you can use `std::sort`?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using the bubble sort algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)

Basically iterate through all records, comparing the current record, with the next. If the current record's 2nd column is higher then swap these records. If the current record's 2nd column is equal but the 3rd column is higher, then swap also.

Continue iterating until no more swaps are made.

To use your example:

10 0 1
11 0 2
12 1 2 (swap with next)
13 0 1

10 0 1
11 0 2(swap with next)
13 0 1
12 1 2

10 0 1
13 0 1
11 0 2
12 1 2

And done!